# Where are all the esoteric collection template libraries?

Tags: c++, collections

**Edit:** What I'm really thinking of is a C++ equivalent to the Contrib libraries other languages enjoy, like [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/)/[PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)/[Ruby Gems](http://rubygems.org/)

Suppose I want a collection type that isn't really supported by anything in the STL or by BOOST, like a spacial index or a fibonacci tree (if i think that might be useful on my really big dataset).  Is there a good place to find these kinds of less common tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes [Vault](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/) has useful things.  maybe you can find something there.

Answer (score 1):

As it is said, google is your friend :-)

It appears that here (http://resnet.uoregon.edu/~gurney_j/jmpc/fib.html) is an implementation of Fibonacci heap in C. Check it out, and if you like it, may be you can translate/modify/improve to a C++.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if there are any actual 'collections of libraries', but i'll start a list of useful libraries.  (C++ libs only, please)

- There's [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), obviously, but also [Boost Vault](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/), which appears to contain libraries that aren't quite ready for inclusion in Boost proper. (thanks [aaa carp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206328/aaa-carp) for pointing this out)
- [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), an arbitrary precision number library, has C++ bindings
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/library/modular-class-library), which is about as old as the moon, but also modern enough to still be useful.  This of course is a heavy handed application library, but there's no real reason not to use whatever parts could be useful.  I'm not too sure how esoteric that really is, though.  Outside of the GUI portions, most functionality would already be duplicated by boost.
- [libCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/) has c++ bindings, for http access (and other things)